# Angular 2 routing component not render properly

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 2 routing in my test project. Already imported routes in Module.ts .
Am Facing issue with Dashboard page on my app .
[Dash page of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSEAm.png)

this dash component contains an event component, which contain an add event button and event listing as shown in image .
i need to add routing for add new event button so that i can render another component which is used for creating new event(event forms).so i have added routerlink for that button like this

```html
<button type="button" routerLink="/addevent" class="btn btn-primary">Add Event</button>

<div class="container">

    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    
   
        <tr>
            
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Modified</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Task Title</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
            


            <tr *ngFor="let evnt of events">
                
                <td>{{evnt.title}}</td>
                <td>{{evnt.created}}</td>
                <td>{{evnt.modified}}</td>
                <td>{{evnt.place}}</td>
                <td>{{evnt.task.title}}</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Del</a></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

and added router outlet in the dash component html since i want the new form field component to be displayed in the dash page by replacing event component.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>


     <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
       <router-outlet>
        <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>              
          <event></event>                        
        </div>
      </router-outlet>

  </div>
</div>
```

**issues :**

1 . while clicking thee add new event button only the new event form component displayed instead the form fields displayed inside dash .
i want the form components to be disaplyed inside the dash by replacing event component .

2. how can i add the same routing option for left menu's on the dash page so that i can render the corresponding components on the right .

Comment: if your dash contains the events, you can't just replace that with a new form. In that case you would have to have the events as a child, and also the new form as a child, which either the form or the events is rendered to routeroutlet in your dash depending on what user chooses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your events is part of your Dashboard Component, you cannot simply replace it with the new form. You said you have a router-outlet on your dash, that means when button is clicked, the new form should render on the dashboard component, along with the events. But you want the events replaced with the form.

One option would be to skip the routes and use divs, hide and show events or new form depending on what user chooses and boolean values.

Otherwise have the router-outlet on your dash, and make `events` and `addevent` as a child components. If you choose this, your routes should looks something like this:

```
.....

path: 'dash',
component: DashboardComponent,
children: [
    {   // shows events as default
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'events',
        pathMatch: 'full' // as per OP's comment, this needs to be added
    },
    {   
        path: 'events', 
        component: EventsComponent,
    },
    {  
        path: 'addevent',
        component: NewEventComponent,
    },
]

....
```

And in your Dashboard you have

```
<div>
  <!-- Dashboard Content here -->
  <button routerLink="/events" class="btn btn-primary">All Events</button>
  <button routerLink="/addevent" class="btn btn-primary">Add Event</button>
</div>

<!-- Either events or new event form rendered here -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

***Worth noticing: Having the dash in routerlink seems to work at least when I tested it, but OP commented that it needed to be removed.***

Comment: it worked with little modifcations from your suggestion . removed '/' from the routerlinks of button and added pathMatch: 'full' for default redirection.thank you its worked

Comment: Yes great that you figured it out. Yeah, I "forgot" to put the pathmatch there, it used to work without it in some other versions of Angular, but now you need `pathMatch` :) But most important this is that you got it to work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't write a comment yet I will put this in an answer.

**Answering question 1:**

it should work if your routes are well defined. Do you have the `/addevent` route in your routes? Can you post the routes?

Another way to do it is: in your html file replace the button with this:

`<button type="button" (click)="addEvent()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Event</button>`

in your component, add this:

```
addEvent(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/newEvent']);
}
```

make sure you import the Router in your component:

`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

and your constructor contains the router:

`constructor(private router: Router) {}`

in your routes you should have this route:

`{ path: 'newEvent', component: EventFormComponent }`

and of course define your EventFormComponent

**Answering question 2:**

replace `href` with `routerLink="/the_name_of_your_route"`

make sure the name_of_your_route exists in your routes.